# How to put MinMaxScaler feature_range in the other way around from positive to negative

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I’m using sklearn to standardise the data. I’m using MinMaxScaler to distribute the data between -2 and 2. Is it possible to do it other way around? I have one column of data where higher number is not better so I would make it other way around when using MinMaxScalar. I tried MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-2,2)*(-1)) but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "make it other way around"? It also would be nice if you can add example code, and data as well as expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. I will use -2, 2 range and then multiply the column with -1.